# Node.js callback unexpected behaviour with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, callback

I am a nodejs beginner and I ran into some callback behaviour that I don't understand.  I am using an Express router to write Mongoose objects to Mongodb using a POST request.  In the body of the request I am passing in a nested json structure with two fields - `jobDetails` and `examples`.  The data in `jobDetails` is used to create a `Job` Mongoose object and the data in `examples` is used to create several `Example` Mongoose objects.  The `Job` and `Example` objects are linked in that a `Job` contains a list of `Example` objects in one of it's fields.

The way I tried to implement this was with callbacks in the following way.  Basically I save the `Job` object to mongo first, then iterate over the examples - each time creating an `Example` object and linking it to the job via the `.job` field and also saving the `Example` object to mongo.  Then in the callback to the `Example` object save function I updated the `Job` object with the new `Example` object and saved the updated version to mongo.

```
router.post('/jobs', function (req, res, next) {
    var job = new Job(req.body.jobDetails);
    var examples = req.body.examples;

    console.log("JOB DETAILS");
    console.log(req.body.jobDetails);

    console.log("EXAMPLES");
    console.log(req.body.examples);

    //save job
    job.save(function (err, job) {
            console.log(err);
    });

     //save examples
     for(i=0; i<examples.length;i++){

        var eg = new Example({content: examples[i]});
        eg.job=job;

        eg.save(function (err, eg){

            job.examples.push(eg);

            job.save(function(err, job){
                 console.log(err);
             });
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

This did not perform as I would expect.  Specifically, double the number of examples were actually saved to mongo with several duplicates and some missing.  I understand that callbacks are asynchronous but to me that still doesn't explain why double the number of examples would be saved and some would be duplicated and some would be missing.

I eventually got it to work correctly without using callbacks at all in the following way.

```
router.post('/jobs', function (req, res, next) {
    var job = new Job(req.body.jobDetails);
    var examples = req.body.examples;

    console.log("JOB DETAILS");
    console.log(req.body.jobDetails);

    console.log("EXAMPLES");
    console.log(req.body.examples);

    //save job
    job.save(function (err, job) {
          console.log(err);
    });

    //save examples
    for(i=0; i<examples.length;i++){

        var eg = new Example({content: examples[i]});
        eg.job=job;

        eg.save(function (err, eg){
            console.log(err);
        });

        job.examples.push(eg);
        job.save(function(err,job){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

And I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution either.  But I would like to know why my original approach resulted in the unintended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
router.post('/jobs', function(req, res, next) {
    var job = new Job(req.body.jobDetails);
    var examples = req.body.examples;

    console.log("JOB DETAILS");
    console.log(req.body.jobDetails);

    console.log("EXAMPLES");
    console.log(req.body.examples);

    //save job
    job.save(function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            //save examples
            for (i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {

                var eg = new Example({
                    content: examples[i]
                });
                eg.job = job;

                eg.save(function(err, eg) {

                    job.examples.push(eg);

                    job.save(function(err, job) {
                        if (!err)
                            job.examples = [];

                    });
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about the ` job.save(function(err, job) {
                        if (!err)
                            job.examples = [];

                    });` part?  Doesn't that just clear all the examples?

Comment: Did it work for you?
This line removed every example after saving it, that means it doesn't add duplicate.

Comment: but all the examples have to be saved in job.examples.  If you clear the examples after each job.save, won't it overwrite all the ones that were saved previously?

Comment: As I am seeing this is not removing all example it just reinitialize current job object's example in every iteration not all the examples, so your all examples will add. It doesn't override since every iteration your are Savin new object in collection

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a library like async to perform such save operations in a step by step manner. Follow this approach for better readability of code and better results

```
var async = require('async');
router.post('/jobs', function(req, res, next) {
    var job = new Job(req.body.jobDetails);
    var examples = req.body.examples;
    var savedExamples = [];

    console.log("JOB DETAILS");
    console.log(req.body.jobDetails);

    console.log("EXAMPLES");
    console.log(req.body.examples);

    async.eachSeries(examples, function iteratee(example, callback) {
        var eg = new Example({
            content: example
        });
        eg.job = job;
        eg.save(function(err, savedEg) {
           if(!err) {
             savedExamples.push(savedEg);
           }
           callback(err)
        });
    }, function(err) {
         if(err) {
            //handle errors
         }
         job.examples = savedExamples;
         job.save(function(err,job) {
            if(err) {
               //handle errors
            }
            //success callback
         });
    });
});
```

Using this approach you will have to call the save function for job only once after all other operations are completed. If an error is triggered at any point the whole flow is stopped. For more info regarding async library refer [this](http://caolan.github.io/async/)!